# Is it possible to generate a Crystal Report for an item in a GridView upon button click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

A little background story:
I have a GridView which contains a list of employees. Above the GridView I have a search text box and LinkButtons which serve as my GridView controls: Add, Edit, Delete, & Generate Reports.

Now back to the main question: Is it possible to select an item in my GridView then click Generate Reports to generate a report containing all of the rows for that selected item? If so, how would I go about in accomplishing this task? Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Thank you!

Here's my code of my GridView:

```
<div style="margin-left:5px; margin-bottom:50px">
                        <div style="margin-bottom:5px; margin-top:5px">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchEquip" runat="server" BorderColor="#666666" style="margin-bottom: 10px; text-align: left;" Width="317px" ForeColor="Black" Height="30px" ></asp:TextBox>  
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSearchEquip" runat="server" Text="Search" Height="30px"/>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnClearEquip" runat="server" Text="Clear" Height="30px"/>
                        </div>
                <asp:GridView ID="gvPersonnelEquipment" CssClass="EU_DataTable" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="SequipID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" PageSize="6" OnRowDataBound="gvEquipment_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="gvPersonnelEquipment_RowCommand">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="SequipID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="SequipID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="SempID" HeaderText="Employee ID" SortExpression="SempID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Equipment" HeaderText="Equipment" SortExpression="Equipment" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="MakeModelNo" HeaderText="Model Number" SortExpression="MakeModelNo" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="PropertyTagNo" HeaderText="Property Tag Number" SortExpression="PropertyTagNo" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="SerialNumber" HeaderText="Serial Number" SortExpression="SerialNumber" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Cost" HeaderText="Cost" SortExpression="Cost" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="EquipmentStatus" HeaderText="Equipment Status" SortExpression="EquipmentStatus" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Remarks" HeaderText="Remarks" SortExpression="Remarks" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="IssuedBy" HeaderText="Issued By" SortExpression="IssuedBy" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="DateIssued" HeaderText="Date Issued" SortExpression="DateIssued" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="RetDate" HeaderText="Return Date" SortExpression="RetDate" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ReceivedBy" HeaderText="Received By" SortExpression="ReceivedBy" />
                        <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" />--%>
                    </Columns>
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#54a1e5" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
                </asp:GridView>
                </div>

                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SecurityDBConnectionString2 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [SecurityPersonnelEquipment] WHERE ([Status] = @Status)" FilterExpression="[Name] LIKE '{0}%' OR [Equipment] LIKE '{1}%' OR [EquipmentStatus] LIKE '{2}%' ">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="1" Name="Status" Type="Int32" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                    <FilterParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearchEquip" Name="Name" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"/>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearchEquip" Name="Equipment" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"/>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearchEquip" Name="EquipmentStatus" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"/>
                    </FilterParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
                <!-- End of Personnel Equipment GridView -->

            </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question is probably too broad to be a good fit for the site, as it asks the answerer to write a lot of code. Your first question "is it possible" is answerable (yes) but questions like "how do i...?" that require large columns of code to be written are generally unanswered (unless they're about sql)

Comment: @CaiusJard Thank you! It's nice to be here. I'm learning more and more everyday. I see your point, however, I'm not asking our friends to write a lot of code for me. As for my question: "How would I go about in accomplishing this task?" I'm just simply asking for direction, advice, or suggestions.. Just to point me towards the right direction.

Comment: There's a slight risk with "how do I" type questions that they will be closed for being opinion based - generally stackoverflow prefers *you* to have the opinion (that some people will then tell you is wrong, hah) and get stuck with some specific detail of he implementation whereupon you ask for help

Comment: That said, when I used to use CR in winforms (never used it in web context) I found it easiest to design the report based on some sample data and include it in my app, then I would have the app run the sql and generate the live data into a DataSet, and give the DataSet to the report as a data source (rather than trying to get CR to run the sql itself). It worked out well, though I've long since lost the code that did it.. in your context the grid view is essentially just a device that picks parameters for the SQL report, in some similar way to a bog standard check/text box…